# Insert columns in one sheet using a for loop through some sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy, multiple-columns

Good morning.

I have one sheet with the next format:

[image: Original Sheet]

And I want it to be like this using vba:

[image: Final Sheet]

So my problem is the following one. I want to get a vba code that inserts columns as the images shown, for example if I have "3 Animals" i'd have to insert a D column and E column between the columns C and D of the firt image.
My workbook has a sheet before this one called Animal 1 but I can have as many sheets as I want, "Animal 2, Animal 3, Animal 4, ...", the problem is I don't know how many I'll have before working. So I want a vba code that gets the number of sheets before this sheet and insert as many columns as sheets I'll have.

The sheets of my Workbook would be: "Title, Description, Animal 1, ... Animal X, CurrentSheet", so I want a code that counts the number of sheets "Animal 1, ... Animal X" and inserts as many columns as sheets there are, like it's shown in the images where it would be an example with only 3 sheets.

I know I have to do it with a for loop but I don't find the way to solve it, sorry i'm quite new in vba.

Thank you so much for your answers and ask me if something it's not clear.

PS: I have working with some code like this:

```
        Dim NumSheet As Long
        Dim I As Long

        NumSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 4 '4 sheets that I don't want to use for the columns insertion

        For I = 1 To NumSheet

            Columns("D:D").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        Next I
```

Comment: Is your question about how to count the number of sheets named "Animal..."?

Comment: Yes, sort of, my question is mostly of how to insert columns depending of how many sheets called "Animal ..." I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counts the number of sheets starting with "Animal" and then inserts that number of columns on another sheet.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, nCount As Long, i As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Animal*" Then nCount = nCount + 1
Next ws

With Sheets("Sheet4")
    .Columns("D:D").Resize(, nCount).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For i = 1 To nCount
        .Cells(1, i + 3).Value = "Price Animal " & i
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works perfectly! Just one more question, is it possible to name the headers of these new columns after copying them? I mean like in the images that the columns D and E are added on the second image and have a name as "Price Animal X".

Comment: Amended above .

Comment: Yes, exactly that! And lastly if you could help: for example the first value of cell "C5" is ```=+'Animal 1'!K2```, "C6" is ```=+'Animal 1'!K3```, is it possible that the value of cell "D5" would be ```=+'Animal 2'!K2``` and so on for the whole new columns?

Comment: I think that's enough questions, time for a new one I think.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll do a new post if I think I cannot get this last one.

Comment: It's just that how the site operates. Thanks for accepting.